# How to debug specific data package in RSA3

Tags: debugging, abap, sap-bw

I'd like to know how one can debug a specific datapackage in `RSA3` transaction. For example, the record in the data package 23 has errors, is there any way that I can put a breakpoint to the data package 23 and so I could observe just only the processing for that specific data package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the form/routine `DATA TRANSFER`, there is a variable `L_DATAPAKID`, here you can put the data package which you want to debug (for example 23). Go to watch point then put your `L_DATAPAKID EQ '000023'` then hit F8. Note: if you use as watch point this `l_datapakid`, you should put a value precedes the actual data package which you want to observe the processing for. So if you want to check data package 23, then put 22 in the `L_DATAPAKID`.

Hope this will help anyone with the same problem.